# IOS UIScrollView with MvvmCross

Tags: ios, binding, uiscrollview, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am writing a "journal" app using MvvmCross for IOS.  For the first View I wanted to have a scrollable list of books which is sourced from a List.

My current implementation is using the viewDidLoad method to dynamically resize the content size of the UIScrollView and add a number of SubViews for each of the books I want to display.

I'd prefer to data bind this but I can't work out the best way to implement a bindable scrollview.  I'd be interested if anyone else has tried something like this before, and if there is a recommended way to do it?

I'm thinking of sub-classing UIScrollView with an ObservableCollection and using collectionchange notifications to re-populate the scrollview content as required.

Thanks for any guidance

Comment: I'm not sure i understand how your ui is unsuitable for a tableview or collectionview. Can you maybe add a sketch of the layout you want to achieve ?

Comment: I was thinking of something like a carousel view where flicking or scrolling sideways would change the selected page.  I hadn't considered a collectionview - That might work nicely if I can put one full size image per page.  I've never worked with collectionviews before, so I'll look into that - thanks for the tip.